# WSL update ошибка: Операция развертывания была заблокирована

Tags: wsl, wsl2

C:\Users\ya-an>wsl --update
Выполняется установка: Подсистема Windows для Linux
Операция развертывания была заблокирована из-за ограничений политики для каждого семейства пакетов, ограничивающей развертывания приложений на несистемном томе. Согласно политике это приложение должно быть установлено на системный диск, но он не является используемым по умолчанию диском. В параметрах хранилища назначьте системный диск используемым по умолчанию расположением сохранения нового содержимого и повторите попытку установки.

Windows 11 23H2 22631.3296

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решилось путём отключения второго диска через диспетчер устройств.
Не знаю что это такое.

Answer (score 0):

У меня тоже вылез прикол этот после обновления wsl. Но диск у меня один. Пока не решил проблему. Заметил что wsl пропал из Windows Store.